# Is it possible to pass a global char variable as a parameter in a function?

Tags: arrays, c, variables, char, global

So I have a global variable called char words[10]. I would like to pass it as a parameter as in a function.

This is the code I have so far and it does not compile obviously. I just do not know how exactly to pass the words variable to the function read_words.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *words[10];

void read_words(*words){
}


int main(){

  read_words(*words);
}
```

Comment: If you want to pass words as a parameter to your function you simply call it as: read_words(words). Your function declaration could be void read_words(char* words_param[10]);

Comment: Please proofread your question. Is it `char words[10]` or `char *words[10]`? They are a very different thing. Also, _what_ are you trying to pass? Exactly 10 words? A single word? Any number of words?

Comment: Also, it being global doesn't matter for this. Make it a local variable in `main` so you don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: **Yes**, you can pass a global variable to a function.

However often there is no need to. This is because any function in the same file as the declaration `char* words[10];` will be able to reference it. Furthermore, if you create new files and `#include` your current file, functions in the new files will also be able to access `words`.

**Note**: To make your program run you have to use pointers correctly, here is a short [intro to pointers](https://www.codesansar.com/c-programming/pointers.htm). If you want `words` to be an array of pointers, you want to pass it to a function as a pointer to a pointer. This modified version of your code should compile:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *words[10];

void read_words(char ** words){
}

int main() {
  read_words(words);
}
```